# What are some use cases for function overriding?

Tags: c++

I'm reviewing some c++ concepts (I used it a few years ago) and the concept of function overloading now makes a LOT of sense to me, especially to some scenarios I encountered in my powershell programming experience over the last year. 
For instance,  now I could easily explain it to someone as its very useful for software refactoring, making code readability easier, etc...

What I dont understand though is the usage/benefit of function overriding. What's some good use cases for it? From research, I just read that it's used for having a different behavior for a child class function in a parent class, but, cant you just name the function in the child class something else, and call it directly that way without worrying about the parent class function?

Comment: Questions like "What's some good use cases for (fundamental computer-science topic)?"  are difficult to answer because the question assumes that there's some simpler alternative that is always substitutable. Your question is like asking a doctor "What's some good use cases for vaccines?" when there is no real alternative to vaccines for preventing disease.

Comment: You should study what's about object oriented programming and what polymorphism is.

Comment: @Dia I did hesitate to post this because I realized it could be ambiguous as you mentioned,  but I genuinely wanted to understand the ”why” and as I am naturally a very curious person, I decided to post, especially since I couldnt find a satisfying answer online. Your answer though makes it clear now, thanks!

Comment: @Moia trust me, I spent a lot of time closely looking at the topic. Now I understand polymorphism a LOT more, and actually makes a lot of sense after years of not understanding the point behind it before my programming intensive job. I am a use case driven person, and the classical way they teach it in university makes it harder for beginners like I once was to understand the WHY and use case behind OOP topics. Like for example, the whole object oriented paradigm was still ambiguous to me even after graduation. Ever since I started using powershell and manipulating psobjects, I.now understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cant you just name the function in the child class something else, and call it directly that way without worrying about the parent class function?

No, because it would be impossible to have runtime dynamic-dispatch which is the entire basis for polymorphism.

(Dynamic-dispatch is implemented in C++ (and most other languages) using vtable-based (`virtual`) calls). Other languages like Objective-C and Smalltalk use a message-passing paradigm. Programs written in C have to implement vtable-calls or message-passing themselves (such as by using function-pointers).

Consider this pseudocode[3] example:

```
class AnyCat {

    abstract void MakeSound();
}

class HouseCat extends AnyCat {

    override void MakeSound() {
        Console.WriteLine( "Meow" );
    }
}

class Lion extends AnyCat {

    override void MakeSound() {
        Console.WriteLine( "Roar" );
    }
}


static void Main() {

    AnyCat cat = GetRandomNumber() % 2 == 0 ? new HouseCat() : new Lion();

    cat.MakeSound(); // <-- this is a vtable/virtual-call
}
```

Because `cat` **could be either** `HouseCat` or `Lion` at runtime, the compiler (and also the programmer!) cannot use a "static call"[4] to `MakeSound`.

---

[3] I'm not using C++'s `class` declaration syntax because it's too verbose and because C++ does not currently require the use of [the `override` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override), so it's not immediately obvious to beginners when a method declaration will result in a vtable call or if it's [just a shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

[4] In this context, "static call" means "statically-compiled" or "fixed at compile-time" in a general-sense (e.g. "statically typed"). It is unrelated to the `static` keyword or `static`-methods in OOP programming languages (though fun fact: all calls to `static` methods are static-calls).

Comment: @TonyTannous My answer intentionally does not use C++ syntax. I've added an explanation to my post why.

Comment: I think you nailed the answer by reiterating this concept I glossed over while reviewing this topic: `it would be impossible to have runtime dynamic-dispatch which is the entire basis for polymorphism.` the book mentioned that it's a type of runtime polymorphism, but it didnt seem to me like the reason to use it, it seemed just like a fun fact sort of statement, but this answer tells me that it's actually the BENEFIT of using it. Thanks!

Comment: One thing if you could possibly emphasize for me is the whole dynamic runtime. I understand that at compile time (e.g. f. overloading) c++ is converted through the interpreter from language to .exe application, then at runtime (e.g. f. Overriding) , it's running the .exe application to see the output. But why is that the case for each of these polymorphism types? Like why doesnt f. Overloading dispatch at runtime as well? Why isnt it dynamic like f. Overriding?

Comment: What do you mean by "these polymorphism types"? And vtable-based dynamic-dispatch has nothing to do with function overloading. (Some languages do support "dynamic double-dispatch" aka "multiple dispatch" where an overload-of-an-override will be chosen at runtime, but C++ does not implement this feature  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch )

Comment: I guess what I mean is, why the compile time and runtime polymorphism? Like why isnt f. overloading dispatched at runtime instead of compile time (in c++)? Maybe I'm confused by what dispatch means/does? At first I understood dispatch with overloading means converting/interpreting the implementation into an executable (compiletime). But isnt all the program language supposed to be that way too? Meaning, f. Overriding should also technically be dispatched at compile time, it shouldn't be directly dispatched at runtime only...

Comment: @Cataster You're confusing vtable-based method **overrides** with function **overloading** - the two are unrelated as far as this conversation is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

You *override* a function in a child class if it needs to have different functionality to that function provided in a base class. An example (remarkably succinct cf. other programming languages):

```
struct Person
{
    virtual ~Person() = default; // make this a polymorphic type
    void bonus()
    {
        throw "Not a chance.";
    }
};

struct Boss : Person
{
    void bonus() // overrides the base class function
    {
        // open banking payment system
        // pay the bonus
        // close the banking payment system
    }
};
```

This sort of classical function overriding is indeed falling out of fashion and is being replaced with *composition*-type patterns. In this case `bonus()` could be a pure virtual function in `Person` which is implemented in each child class.

Comment: unfortunately this classical way of distributing bonusses isnt coming out of fashion

Comment: Interesting! Thanks